# JQuery - SyntaxError: reserved word "this" can't be assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to loop through a variable in JQuery and reassign the value of `this` in the following Coffeescript.

```
$.each data.rows, ->
  completion_time = [this[0], new Date(new Date('Jan 01 2000').getTime() +  this[1])]
  this = completion_time
```

However this produces the following error message:

> SyntaxError: reserved word "this" can't be assigned

On each iteration the value of `this` looks something like this:

> **["abc123", 12302103, 1230132, 1230123]**

What I'm trying to do is reassign it to the value of:

> **["abc123", 12302103]**

I tried assigning `this.value` as well, no dice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reassign `this`. You can modify `this` to contain the elements in the new array

I can't stand CoffeScript, so I'll just show it in JS

```
// Clear elements from the array
this.length = 0;
// Add each element in the new array
this.push.apply(this, completion_time);
```

Comment: @JaunMendes Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. Is there a particular reason why `this` can't be reassigned to something else?

Comment: Yes, because `this` points to the object itself, reassigning it would only work for the variable you're looking at. You would need a reference to the object to be able to reassign it, and JS doesn't have those types of references, it's always a pointer to the object, never a pointer to a pointer, if that makes any sense. A different way to explain it, changing `this` would not change all the existing references to the same object. By mutating `this` instead of reassigning it, all the other references to the object will be affected

Comment: @CyleHunter Consider how non-sensical it would be to write `this=null`, you'd have invalidate the object that you're working with...

Comment: It's a little tricky to wrap my head around, but indeed that would be nonsensical. I was under the impression `this`, as per the context it was given was simply an attribute of another object. Rather it's an object in and of itself that simply references the context that I was giving it. Thanks for the explanation.